# WordPress custom meta-boxes not saving with multiple fields per box

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I created a custom meta-box in WordPress that contains multiple fields in the same box. The issue I am having is that when I type into the fields in the WP admin, the changes are not saved.

I created a save function already. The save works fine with meta boxes that contain only one field, but not with multiple fields.

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init(){
add_meta_box("report-pdf-meta-01", "Report PDF #1", "report_pdf_01", "report", "normal", "high");
}

function save_details(){
       global $post;

       update_post_meta($post->ID, "report_pdf_01", $_POST["report_pdf_01"]);
       update_post_meta($post->ID, "report_pdf_title_01", $_POST["report_pdf_title_01"]);
}

   function report_pdf_01(){
       global $post;
       $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
       $report_pdf_01 = $custom["report_pdf_01"][0];
       $report_pdf_title_01 =  $custom["report_pdf_title_01"][0];
       ?>
<p><label>PDF Field:</label>
<input name="report_pdf_01" value="<?php echo $report_pdf_01; ?>" />
<p><label>Button Title:</label>
<input name="report_pdf_title_01" value="<?php echo $report_pdf_title_01; ?>" /></p>
<?php
   }
```

I assumed this would cause the fields to save since the other boxes did when set up with one field the same way, but so far this is not the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct however I would suggest a few modifications which are as mentioned below:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details', 10, 2);
add_action("admin_init", "register_custom_metaboxes"); //renaming the function so as to avoid confusion and conflicts.
function register_custom_metaboxes(){
    add_meta_box("report-pdf-meta-01", "Report PDF #1", "report_pdf_01", "report", "normal", "high");
}
function save_details($id, $post_data){
    //The $post_data object and current post ID are available to us to begin with.
    //Some necessary capabilities check mentioned below.
    if (!current_user_can("edit_post", $id)) {
        return $post_data;
    }
    if (defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_data;
    }
    //Just making sure that we are getting the correct data and to verify the received field names we log it into the file which will be created at the root directory level.
    error_log('Posted Data : '.print_r($_POST, true).PHP_EOL, 3, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/post.log");
    //sanitizing the data before saving.
    update_post_meta($id, "report_pdf_01", sanitize_text_field($_POST["report_pdf_01"]));
    update_post_meta($id, "report_pdf_title_01", sanitize_text_field($_POST["report_pdf_title_01"]));
}
function report_pdf_01(){
    global $post;
    //Retrieving post meta data by individual key in singular format and not array.
    $report_pdf_01 = get_post_meta($post->ID, "report_pdf_01", true);
    $report_pdf_title_01 =  get_post_meta($post->ID, "report_pdf_title_01", true);
    ?>
    <p><label>PDF Field:</label>
    <input name="report_pdf_01" value="<?php echo $report_pdf_01; ?>" />
    <p><label>Button Title:</label>
    <input name="report_pdf_title_01" value="<?php echo $report_pdf_title_01; ?>"/></p>
    <?php
}
```